# Ruby on Rails, Redirect After Creating New Post in Note Taking App

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my RoR note taking application notes are called Statuses.

When a user creates and posts a new Status, I would like them to be redirected to the Satuses page, an index of all of their Statuses/Notes.

Right now they are redirected to a page that shows just that new Status/Note.

I thought this would be a simple rediect in the Statuses controller, the Create action, but it isn't. A friend coded this part of the app and the JSON and render commands there have thrown me off a bit.

Here is the code from the controller:

```html
# POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = current_user.statuses.new(params[:status])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And from the entry form partial:

```html
  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class = "small-3 small-centered columns text-center">
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: "radius button text-center" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using redirect_to @status which redirects to show page of status.

To redirect to index page use following code

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @status.save
    format.html { redirect_to statuses_path, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```